# How do I verify if the cudatools public key is valid? Or rather how should I verify any public key as valid?

Tags: linux, authentication, gnupg, pgp

I've downloaded the public key for cudatools from the nvidia site. But, how do I verify the validity of this key? A lookup for the key in the various pgp servers, such as pgp.mit.edu, keys.openpgp.org, doesn't reveal anything.

Does everyone rely on https and website dns to determine the authenticity of downloaded keys, or do they rely on other pgp keyserver sites to double verify the downloaded keys?